# How can I update angular bindings with data from a getUserMedia stream?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, getusermedia

I'm using getUserMedia to get an audio stream. The audio stream is only available in the callback from getUserMedia. However, when I try to update the bindings from inside the callback, angular doesn't detect the changes and doesn't update the bindings. I've tried to use $scope.$apply as suggested by many articles, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Here is a fiddle that shows what I've tried.
http://jsfiddle.net/poptart911/a00koc8r/1/

```
    angular.module('test', [])
    .controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
    this.deviceStatus = "Angular works.";
    this.deviceStatus = "We can update a binding.";
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: false
    }).then(function (stream) {
        this.deviceStatus = "Angular doesn't detect this change.";
        $scope.$apply(function (stream) {
            this.deviceStatus = "I even tried scope.apply!";
            alert("But I know this code is executing");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope.$apply` is working as expected.  However, the scope of `this` refers to the scope of the inner lambda function, not the scope of the outer function where `deviceStatus` is first declared.  As a result, the `getUserMedia` callback creates a *new* `deviceStatus` variable instead of altering the original variable (to which the UI is bound).  Try storing a reference to the original `this` and use it when referencing `deviceStatus` in your inner lambda function:

```
angular.module('test', [])
    .controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
        var that = this;
        that.deviceStatus = "Angular works.";
        that.deviceStatus = "We can update a binding.";
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            audio: true,
            video: false
        }).then(function (stream) {
            that.deviceStatus = "*Now* angular detects this change.";
            $scope.$apply(function (stream) {
                that.deviceStatus = "I even tried scope.apply!";
                alert("But I know this code is executing");
            });
       });
});
```

[Here's a working jsfiddle as a demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/NathanFriend/9prvnrnv/).  The `getUserMedia` function has been replaced with a `setTimeout` since that function didn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood how variables were being closed around. Thanks!